# Get the Values of an image in Python

Tags: python, image, gdal

I have a `GeoTIFF` and I need to get the values of each pixel.

I proceeded this way :

```
import gdal
from gdalconst import *

im = gdal.Open("test.tif", GA_ReadOnly)
band = im.GetRasterBand(1)
bandtype = gdal.GetDataTypeName(band.DataType)
scanline = band.ReadRaster( 0, 0, band.XSize, 1,band.XSize, 1, band.DataType)
```

scanline contains uninterpretable values :

```
>>> scanline
'\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19
\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19\xfc\
x19\xfc\x19\xfc\x19...
```

I need to convert this data to readable values.

In other words, I need to get the values of the image in order to count the number of pixels having values greater than a specified threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ReadAsArray instead.

```
//for float data type
scanline = band.ReadAsArray( 0, 0, band.XSize, band.YSize).astype(numpy.float)
```

refer to website : [link](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

From the gdal [tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html), "Note that the returned scanline is of type string, and contains xsize*4 bytes of raw binary floating point data. This can be converted to Python values using the struct module from the standard library:"

```
import struct
tuple_of_floats = struct.unpack('f' * b2.XSize, scanline)
```

Alternatively, depending on what you are ultimately trying to do with the data, you could read it in as an array (which opens the door to using numpy for computations).

```
import gdal

im = gdal.Open("test.tif", GA_ReadOnly)
data_array = im.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
```